# Loading multiple images in pygame background

Tags: python, pygame

working on importing several jpgs as a stationary background and tile them into one picture.  I have it working, just looks really ugly.  Is there a better way, or at least prettier way of doing this:

```
import pygame

from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

background0 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map01.jpg'
background1 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map02.jpg'
background2 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map03.jpg'
background3 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map04.jpg'
background4 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map05.jpg'
background5 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map06.jpg'
background6 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map07.jpg'
background7 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map08.jpg'
background8 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map09.jpg'
background9 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map10.jpg'
background10 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map11.jpg'
background11 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map12.jpg'
background12 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map13.jpg'
background13 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map14.jpg'
background14 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map15.jpg'
background15 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map16.jpg'
background16 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map17.jpg'
background17 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map18.jpg'
background18 = 'Screens\\Map\\Map19.jpg'

ground = [ background0, background1, background2, background3, background4, background5,
background6, background7, background8, background9, background10, background11,
background12, background13, background14, background15, background16, background17,
background18]
mouse_image = 'pygame\\Pygame_HW\\fugu.png'

new_resolution_x = 1000
new_resolution_y = 760

scale_x = new_resolution_x / 16120.0
scale_y = new_resolution_y / 19000.0

pic_wid = 16120 * scale_x
pic_height = 1000 * scale_y

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((new_resolution_x, new_resolution_y), 0, 16)
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World!")


for i in range(19):
    ground[i] = pygame.image.load(ground[i])
    ground[i] = pygame.transform.scale(ground[i], (int(pic_wid), int(pic_height)))


 mouse_cursor = pygame.image.load(mouse_image).convert_alpha()

while True:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()

screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
for i in range(19):

    screen.blit(ground[i], (0,i * int(pic_height)))

x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
x -= mouse_cursor.get_width() / 2
y -= mouse_cursor.get_height() / 2
screen.blit(mouse_cursor, (x, y))

pygame.display.update()
```

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, more or less what te people are suggesting, and some identation problems, if not caused by `SO` code sample format:

```
import pygame

from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

#you should rename the Map# from 1 to 9 instead of 01 to 09.
ground = ['Map'+ str(image+1) +'.jpg' for image in range(19)]

mouse_image = 'pygame\\Pygame_HW\\fugu.png'

new_resolution_x = 1000
new_resolution_y = 760

scale_x = new_resolution_x / 16120.0
scale_y = new_resolution_y / 19000.0

pic_wid = 16120 * scale_x
pic_height = 1000 * scale_y

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((new_resolution_x, new_resolution_y), 0, 16)
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World!")

#at this for you can manipulate the string inside of image.load
#method instead of using unecessary memory re - saving the full path
for i in range(19):
    ground[i] = pygame.image.load('Screens\\Map\\' + str(ground[i]))
    ground[i] = pygame.transform.scale(ground[i], (int(pic_wid), int(pic_height)))
    #or in one line ground[i] = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Screens\\Map\\' + str(ground[i])), (int(pic_wid), int(pic_height)))

 mouse_cursor = pygame.image.load(mouse_image).convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
           pygame.quit()
           exit()

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        for i in range(19):
           screen.blit(ground[i], (0,i * int(pic_height)))

        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x -= mouse_cursor.get_width() / 2
        y -= mouse_cursor.get_height() / 2
        screen.blit(mouse_cursor, (x, y))

       pygame.display.update()
```

You can reduce it to a line of code, but the person who did the code would not understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand what you really want here, but you can simplify the first part by:

```
ground = ["mydirectory//map"+str(number)+".jpg" for number in range(1,20)]
```

But in all case, it's bad to define directory in this way and construct file like this ;)

After that, it's more a programming style. You can add object or/and function and true structure to the code. But it's a completly different code after that.

Maybe you can take a look to game loop engine.

you may have a simplify loop engine like that:

```
def run_engine():
    while (treat_event())
        modify_word()
        draw_graphics()

load_data()
run_engine()
```

Better with a object structure, with a game manager, a event manager, and so on...
But I think you must start by create function and structure the code

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this

```
background_dir = 'Screens\\Map'
background_files = ['Map%02d' % i for i in range(1, 20)]
ground = [image.load(os.path.join(backgroup_dir, file)) for file in background_files]
```

- then blit them all into one surface
- then scale that whole surface to the size you want

Or maybe just chuck the idea and put them all into 1 image.  Is there a reason you are not?

Comment: I'm having to clean up someone else's mess, and this is the format they had them in.  Something else I am having to contend with is the fact that for some reason he has a resolution of 16,120 x 19,000 when all 19 images are put together.  Which seems really silly to me when even HDMI resolution is standard at 1920 x 1080

Comment: @user3461628 storing high res and scaling to low is a good way to go, but storing that high of resolution seems a bit extreme.  Maybe future proofing?  You could change the formatting of the image to something more reasonable.